# Replace the first 20 elements in a list with 0 in Python

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list with 1259 elements and would like to replace the first 20 values of that list with a 0. How would you do this the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple while loop to do the job, should be easy to understand:

```
counter = 0
        
while counter < 20:
    list[counter] = 0
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
lst[:20] = [0] * 20
```

Should work just fine.

Or even:

```py
for i in range(20): lst[i] = 0
```

This one is actually more space efficient and does not compromise speed either, but I find the first solution more elegant.

Comment: The first solution will construct a temporary list of 20 zeros. I like the slice assignment, but how about using a generator e.g. `lst[:20] = (0 for _ in range(20))`?

Comment: In the generator case I think the whole RHS is also constructed before being assigned to the slice on the LHS, so you do not gain anything. But I might be wrong. I will do some benchmarking to see the performance difference. The space difference is harder to benchmark.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Hmm, interesting... Can you think of a way to test whether this is the case?

Comment: @alaniwi The generator approach is about a factor of 8 slower on this example (probably because it is very small number of elements). I am still unclear as to how to benchmark the space requirement. Probably the only way to be sure is to check the Python source code when doing slice assignments. I always assumed that slice assignment is handled in "one go", and thus the RHS has to be evaluated fully before being assigned to the LHS.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa It occurred to me that one could test it with a generator function that inspects the list when you iterate over it. If the list has not yet been updated with the values from the earlier iterations, then the values must be being stored somewhere else.  Going to have a play...

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Just seen your last comment and tried it - if the generator is longer or shorter than the number of elements you are trying to replace, you don't get an error, you change the length of the list.

Comment: I deleted the comment after I realized that as well. It does so because it replaces the slice with a new list. Wow, you have to be careful when working with slices.

Comment: This is super fascinating, I've been messing around with it and honestly so clueless as to how lists are implemented in python now haha

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Right, I've tried it with a generator function of my own that simply prints the list before it `yield`s 0 (all in a loop over number of iterations), and the list is the unmodified original list each time. This means that you are correct - it must be the case that it is storing these values in memory somewhere outside of the target list (presumably a temporary list).

Comment: @MZ In view of the above, I have edited the answer to remove my earlier suggestion that you added - there is no gain in it.

Comment: @alaniwi it was definitely an interesting python rabbit hole though, and in writing still quite elegant

Comment: @MZ Yes but it seems that the memory-efficient solution is going to be a simple `for` loop :)

Comment: @alaniwi for efficiency, it almost always is :)